# Travis CI showing build error for my expressjs app despite showing all tests passed

Tags: node.js, express

I have integrated Travis CI into my github repo called Banka which contains expressjs application and some html and css files.

On building, travis shows all my test which I wrote in mocha and chai as passing but yet it finally reports "build error" and surprisingly enough, can't point where the error is.

I changed to latest node and npm versions and still, no change

--package.json

{
  "name": "Banka",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "~10.15.3",
    "npm": "~6.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.5",
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "debug": "~2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^1.2.0",
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "express-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "jade": "~1.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.0.2",
    "mocha": "^6.1.2",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "request": "~2.51.0"
  }

### }

Here is what Travis is showing : https://travis-ci.com/NawasNaziru/Banka/builds/108177363

I expect to see "build passing" since, all my tests passed.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is that mocha doesn't close and handover to Travis after running the written tests. Hence, the reason why, travis reports timeout. To fix that, simply add the --exit flag in your package.json next to mocha like this

{
  "test" : "mocha --exit"
   ......
}